# CRM Javascript: Getting Email Address of the Participant List

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm

In CRM 2013 I'm writing a javascript to remove certain email participants that contains a specific email address (in my code below it's test@test.com).

I was told that the best way to do this is to remove the whole email participants and re-build it, because there is no good way of just removing a specific participant from the email (please correct me if there's a better way).

So first I get all of the party in the "to" field in the email. Then I push the 'satisfactory' participants into a new array. The participants that contain test@test.com email will not be pushed into this new array i.e. get dropped from the list.

However I'm having problem trying to get the email address value from the "toParty" list.

This doesn't seem to work and returning undefined instead. Here I'm going by the email's schema name which is 'EMailAddress1'. Trying 'emailaddress1' doesn't work either.

```
toParty[indxAttendees].EMailAddress1 --> doesn't work
```

Any ideas is greatly appreciated.

```
var toParty = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("to").getValue();

    for (var indxAttendees = 0; indxAttendees < toParty.length; indxAttendees++) {


        var partyListData = new Array();

        if (toParty[indxAttendees].EMailAddress1 != "test@test.com") 
        {

            //alert("Email address " + indxAttendees + " :" + toParty[indxAttendees].EMailAddress1); --> this will be undefined value
            partyListData[indxAttendees] = new Object();

            //get ID
            partyListData[indxAttendees].id = toParty[indxAttendees].id;
            alert("ID " + indxAttendees + " :" + toParty[indxAttendees].id);

            //get Name
            partyListData[indxAttendees].name = toParty[indxAttendees].name;
            alert("Name " + indxAttendees + " :" + toParty[indxAttendees].name);               

            partyListData[indxAttendees].entityType = toParty[indxAttendees].entityType;
            alert("Entity Type " + indxAttendees + " :" + toParty[indxAttendees].entityType);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using oDataQuery works in this case. Just have to write different function for queue since the email address field is different in queue vs. contact/account.

```
if ((entityType == "contact") || (entityType == "account")) {
    select = "$select=EMailAddress1&$filter=" + entityType.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + entityType.slice(1) + "Id eq guid'" + entityId + "'";        
    var entitySet = entityType.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + entityType.slice(1) + "Set";

    XrmServiceToolkit.Rest.RetrieveMultiple(entitySet, select,
   function (results) {
       if (results.length > 0) {
           result = results[0].EMailAddress1;
       }
   }, function (error) { alert(error); }, function onComplete() { }, false);
        return result;
}
```